# Notation of the Radon-Nikodym derivative

Tags: derivatives, notation, radon-nikodym

A question regarding notation of the radon nikodym derivative:
If the derivative $\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}:=f$ exists, some authors write something like $d\nu = f d\mu$, i.e., they treat the derivative as if it was an actual fraction and plug in $f d\mu$ for $d\nu$ etc.

My problem, however: I dont know what this is expression is supposed to mean since $\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}$ is not an actual fraction of course but only the notation for a specific function. So what does the expression $d\nu = f d\mu$ mean?

Comment: I would say it's a shorthand for $\int d\nu = \int fd\mu$, just omitted the integral.

Comment: This is a great question, but also one which has been asked many times before on this site. See discussion in answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/828441/question-on-integral-notation-and-nikodym-derivative), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1373806/intuition-for-probability-density-function-as-a-radon-nikodym-derivative/2171193#2171193) for instance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Question on integral, notation and Nikodym derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/828441/question-on-integral-notation-and-nikodym-derivative). Also see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4513984/why-are-measures-sometimes-defined-as-differentials/4514026#4514026)

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. However, I dont find the answers in these threads necessarily satisfying. In particular, I still dont see how it is justified to say $\int g d\nu=\int g f d\mu$. I.e., in that example ppl who use that notation suggest that they would simply substitute the infinitesimals via $d\nu = f d\mu$ but again, this shouldnt be allowed because there is no reason we should be allowed to treat the radon nikodym derivative $f=\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}$ like an actual fraction.

Comment: So looking at the wikipedia of radon nikodym, if g is integrable and $\nu$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. to $\mu$, then $\int g d\nu = \int g \frac{d\nu}{d\mu}d\mu$. This is actually the theorem that ppl use implicitely. But it requires $g$ to be integrable which ppl seem not to care about when using the abusive notation $d\nu = f d\mu$ and substitute it as they wish.